# ReactJS: Empty input field after processing its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to empty an input field in my react component after the content has been stored to the DB. This is what I did so far:

```
addPost (event) {
  const content = event.target.value

  methodInsert.call(
    { content },
    (error) => {
      if (!error) {
        event.target.value = ''
      }
    }
  )
}
```

**render()**

```
<Input
   onBlur={this.addPost.bind(this)}
/>
```

I am getting the error

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons.
If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null.
If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
```

Comment: Great! And what's the problem?

Comment: Make the input controlled and then setState to an empty string.

Comment: @PeterMader See updated post

Comment: Can you also post the portion where you're using this function. Maybe you forgot to bind the function to correct `this` wherever you using this function

Comment: did using event.persist work? but I would suggest you use the `setState` method as suggested by @SamHH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an `onChange` handler on your input that updates the state of the component when anything changes. You'll also need a `onSubmit` handler to handle your submit logic and then clear the input by using `this.setState` to set it's value to empty.

I recommend you read about [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in the React documentation.

Here is an example of how this can be accomplished:

```
class Example extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        this.state = {
            inputValue = ""
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind( this );
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind( this );
    }

    handleChange( e ) {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // .. do your stuff and then
        this.setState({
            inputValue: ""
        });
    }

    render() {
        <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Controlled input"
                   onChange={ this.handleChange }
                   value={ this.state.inputValue } />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    }
}
```

Comment: But after submitting, the value of input field still persists. It should be empty.

Comment: @user3142695 my mistake... I forgot to include `value={ this.state.inputValue }` on the `<input />`. Go ahead and check the update it will work now :)